# Fatal error occuring when created a module in presatshop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a back office(bo) module to view  the dormant users in bo,
I created module and module  is  installing correctly and menu is been created   and  I am able to uninstall  it properly , but when i click  the menu 'Dormant users' I am getting error in  functions.php, i haven't touched  this page .

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DormantUsers::viewAccess() in D:\xampp\htdocs\raffleV1.1\oknr9hexztcseff5\functions.php on line 279

Here is the link to my module 
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlg6623jwyx4nnp/dormantusers.zip?dl=0
extract and try and please  check why this eror occurs. I am  trying to solve this for more than 3 hours now , could not find any hint ,

What i did is the following 
I created  dormantusers folder in modules folder and created dormantusers.php and  below is the code  in that page .

```
 <?php
 if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) exit;

class DormantUsers extends Module
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'dormantusers';
    $this->tab = 'others';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'KITS';
    $this->need_instance = 0;

    /**
     * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
     */
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();
    $this->displayName = $this->l('DormantUsers');
    $this->description = $this->l('Allow your Back Office to View Dormant Users ');
    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('You want to Uninstall DormantUsers ?.');
    $this->_tabsArray = array(
    'DormantUsers' => 'Dormant Users',        
    );
}

/**
 * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
 * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
 */
public function install()
{
    return parent::install() && $this->_installTabs();
}

private function _installTabs()
{
    $parentTab = new Tab();
    foreach (Language::getLanguages() as $language) $parentTab->name[$language['id_lang']] = 'Dormant Users';
    $parentTab->class_name = 'DormantUsers';
    $parentTab->module = $this->name;
    $parentTab->id_parent = 0;
    if (!$parentTab->save()) return false;
    else {
        $idTab = $parentTab->id;
        //$idEn = Language::getIdByIso('en');
        foreach ($this->_tabsArray as $tabKey => $name) {
            $childTab = new Tab();

            foreach (Language::getLanguages() as $language) $childTab->name[$language['id_lang']] = $name;

            $childTab->class_name = $tabKey;
            $childTab->module = $this->name;
            $childTab->id_parent = $idTab;

            if (!$childTab->save()) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}



public function uninstall()
{

    $this->_uninstallTabs();
    return parent::uninstall();
}


private function _uninstallTabs()
{
    foreach ($this->_tabsArray as $tabKey => $name) {
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabKey);
        if ($idTab != 0) {
            $tab = new Tab($idTab);
            $tab->delete();
        }
    }

    $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName('DormantUsers');
    if ($idTab != 0) {
        $tab = new Tab($idTab);
        $tab->delete();
    }
    return true;
}




/**
 * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be loaded in the BO.
 */
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
    }
}
 }
```

In the controllers folder controllers/admin/DormantUsersController.php  have the following code .

```
 <?php
 require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'dormantusers/dormantusers.php');
 require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'dormantusers/classes/DormantUsers.php');
 class DormantUsersController extends ModuleAdminController
 {
    public $module;
    public $html;
    public $tabName = 'renderForm';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tab = 'dormantusers';
    $this->module = new dormantusers();        
    $this->addRowAction('view');
    $this->explicitSelect = false;
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    $this->id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
    $this->lang = false;
    $this->ajax = 1;
    $this->path = _MODULE_DIR_.'dormantusers';
    $this->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;

    $this->table = 'customers';
    $this->className = 'DormantUsers';
    $this->identifier = 'id_customer';
    $this->allow_export = true;
    $this->_select = '
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    nationality,
    passport_no,
    date_add
    ';

    $this->name = 'DormantUsers';
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    $this->initList();
    parent::__construct();
}


 private function initList()
  {
   $this->fields_list = array(
    'firstname' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('First Name'),
    'width' => 140,
    'type' => 'text',
    ),
    'lastname' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Last Name'),
    'width' => 140,
    'type' => 'text',
    ),
    'email' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Email'),
    'width' => 140,
    'type' => 'text',       
    ),
    'nationality' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Nationality'),
    'width' => 140,
    'type' => 'text',       
    ),
    'date_add' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('date add'),
    'width' => 140,
    'type' => 'text',
    ),
    'passport_no' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('passport_no'),
    'width' => 140,
    'type' => 'text',
    ),
);
$helper = new HelperList();     
$helper->shopLinkType = '';     
$helper->simple_header = true;

// Actions to be displayed in the "Actions" column
$helper->actions = array('view');

$helper->identifier = 'id_customer';
$helper->show_toolbar = true;
$helper->title = 'HelperList';

$helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
$helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
   return $helper;
}
public function initPageHeaderToolbar()
{
    $this->page_header_toolbar_title = $this->l('Dormant Users List ');
    parent::initPageHeaderToolbar();
}

public function initToolbar()
{
    parent::initToolbar();

    $this->context->smarty->assign('toolbar_scroll', 1);
    $this->context->smarty->assign('show_toolbar', 1);
    $this->context->smarty->assign('toolbar_btn', $this->toolbar_btn);

}   

public function postProcess()
{   
    parent::postProcess();

 }  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define function viewAccess in DormantUsersController class. Try this code

```
public function viewAccess($disable = false)
{
    if (version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.5.1.0', '<='))
        return true;
    return parent::viewAccess($disable);

}
```